# Unable to find the default new form for list

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am creating the External list  in VS 2010 with CRUD methods and deployed the list in site. While i am clicking the add new item it showing the Unable to find the new form for list <External List name> in share point 2010 (BCS).

Following is the error

---

Unable to find the default new form for list Activity. Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. Correlation ID: e3f1889d-70d9-4633-85b5-9f30b24d4d17 Date and Time: 7/12/2010 10:01:38 AM

Comment: You have to provide *some* info, at least the exact error message.

Comment: Unable to find the default new form for list Activity. 

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 

Correlation ID: e3f1889d-70d9-4633-85b5-9f30b24d4d17 

Date and Time: 7/12/2010 10:01:38 AM

Comment: above is the error showing in the window

Comment: a more descriptive title may help too...

Answer (score 0):

While not the direct answer, I think this will provide additional information about the problem so a better answer can be given.  [ULS Viewer](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer) is a tool that will provide additional information about the error and often the steps leading up to the error.  You can filter the ULS results by the Correlation ID, which is usually, but not always in the ULS logs.